# get variables cookies (javascript)

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can i use the variable "food" saved in the cookie.

Its because all my variables are deleted when i refresh my webpage and i must save them for use the after.

```
function guardar() {
name= "materiales";
value = food;
caduca = "31 Dec 2020 23:59:59 GMT";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+";expire= "+caduca;
}

function ReadCookie(){
alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; ++i) 
     {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
           return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
     }
   return "";
}
```

**Function explained:**

Take the cookiename as parameter `(cname)`.

Create a variable `(name)` with the text to search for `(cname + "=")`.

Split document.cookie on semicolons into an array called ca `(ca = document.cookie.split(';'))`.

Loop through the ca array `(i=0; i < ca.length; ++i)`, and read out each value trimmed `(c = ca[i].trim())`.

If the cookie is found `(c.indexOf(name) == 0)`, return the value of the cookie `(c.substring(name.length,c.length)`.

If the cookie is not found, `return ""`.

see : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp